# RoR - collection_select from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, collections

I've a little array:

```
@dates= ['2013-11-01', '2013-11-02', '2013-11-03', '2013-11-04', '2013-11-05']
```

how can i put these array in an collection_select in the view? I tried:

```
...    
<%= f.collection_select :day, Day.order(:date), :id, @dates, include_blank: false %>
...
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming that you mean to use the date strings for both the value (returned from form) and text (displayed in drop-down) of the select then

```
= f.collection_select :day, @dates, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: false
```

This will pass :to_s to each element of the the @dates collection and use the results for the text (param 3) and value (param 4) of the select.