# Display collection_select dropdown with dates in words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown with collection_select for some dates, but I am struggling to display the dates in words as times from now (i.e. "One month from today")

So far I have:

```
def dates_for_review_select
    [Date.today, (Date.today + 2.weeks), (Date.today + 1.month), (Date.today + 2.months), (Date.today + 3.months)]
end
```

and

```
<%= f.collection_select :uk_review_at, dates_for_review_select, :to_s, :to_s, {}, :class => "form-control" %>
```

(from here -> [RoR - collection_select from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122257/ror-collection-select-from-array))

But I don't know how to change how the dates are displayed. At the moment it is displaying them as normal dates, but I want them to display using the rails "distance_of_time_in_words" helper, so it says how far away the date is in words.

But I don't know how or where to implement this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options_for_select` will take an array of arrays, the first element of each sub array is the display value, the second element is the value returned.

So this should work...

```
def dates_for_review_select
    [Date.today, (Date.today + 2.weeks), (Date.today + 1.month), (Date.today + 2.months), (Date.today + 3.months)]
end

<%= f.select :uk_review_at, options_for_select(dates_for_review_select.map{|d| [distance_of_time_in_words(Date.today, d), d]}), {}, :class => "form-control review-date" %>
```

Edited to use the final version that camillavk used.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, although I modified it to be: `<%= f.select :uk_review_at, options_for_select(dates_for_review_select.map{|d| [distance_of_time_in_words(Date.today, d), d]}), {}, :class => "form-control review-date" %>`

Comment: Great. I've modified the answer to use your final result (as that presumably will be more useful for people searching for answers in the future).

Answer (score 0):

You can improve readability by passing `dates_for_review_select` as the collection object, `:itself` as the value function, and a `lambda` using `distance_of_time_in_words` for the text function.

```
<%= f.collection_select(
      :uk_review_at,
      dates_for_review_select,
      :itself,
      -> (t) { distance_of_time_in_words(Date.today, t) },
      class: 'form-control review-date') %>
```